# Ubuntu 13.04 Release Cycle?

Tags: 13.04

What do you mean by support?  do you mean technical support or do you mean you stop fixing problems when the 9 months is up?

Answer (score 0):

It means on everything, from Ubuntu Wiki " When an Ubuntu release reaches its “end of life” it receives no further maintenance updates, including critical security upgrades. It is highly recommended that you upgrade to a recent version of Ubuntu at this point."

Thats saying all Bugs fixing , Security updates , updates, Upgrades about system and applications everything .

Answer (score 0):

It means all support that you can find on this site:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/support

It also means that it receives further maintenance updates, including critical security upgrades.

And also you can get answers at your questions referring to the current releases here on http://askubuntu.com.

After each version of Ubuntu has reached its [end-of-life (EOL)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) time, its repositories are removed from the main Ubuntu servers and consequently the mirrors. Support that you will get will be:

> It is highly recommended that you upgrade to a recent version of Ubuntu at this point.

Also questions about EOL Ubuntu releases are off topic on this site and you will be redirected to:

- [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Brother , OP asking the Life after 9 months & not before 9 months.:)

Comment: @rajagenupula No, he asked: *What do you mean by support?* Anyway, I clarified my answer.